# how to capture the results of search python dictionary

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

#I have a data frame like this, what i am trying to do is to search the Description column it see if it contain the string in my dictionary by using for loops. the results look good for me but have do not know how to save it to data frame or list or any sort of file i can export it :

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ID':  ['1', '2'],
        'Description': ['there is a good book which is best for kids.', 'there is a bad book which worst for kids.'],
    
        }
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['ID','Description'])

myDict={'A':{'best', 'good'}, 'D':{'bad','worst'}}

for i in range(len(df)):
   for key, val in myDict.items():
       for item in val:
           if item in df['Description'][i]: 
              print(item)
              print(i) 

good
0
best
0
bad
1
worst
1

###output should like this.  how do i create a dataframe  or list to capture the results
#0 good best
#1 bad worst
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing the matches, append them to a list containing the matches for the current row of the dataframe. Then append the list that row of results to the list of results.

```
result = []

for i in range(len(df)):
    row = [i]
    for key, val in myDict.items():
        for item in val:
            if item in df['Description'][i]: 
                row.append(item)
    result.append(row)
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar! your solution is better !!

Comment: The solution of daodennis is good too, specially when the dictionary items have uneven values. It maybe easer to convert to dataframe later.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to aggregate the results in some data structure even as a list of tuples potentially? I added two lines to your code snippet:

results = []

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ID':  ['1', '2'],
        'Description': ['there is a good book which is best for kids.', 'there is a bad book which worst for kids.'],
    
        }
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['ID','Description'])

myDict={'A':{'best', 'good'}, 'D':{'bad','worst'}}

results = [] # aggregate results into a list
for i in range(len(df)):
   for key, val in myDict.items():
       for item in val:
           if item in df['Description'][i]: 
              print(item)
              print(i) 
              results.append((item, i)) # results[("good", 0), ("best", 0), ...]


# You can print them out like this
for x, y in results:
  print("{} {}".format(x,y))
```

Comment: Thanks daodennis, it works .  I did that before and get error mess said str object is not appendable .  Thanks !!!